# Call javascript program on body click with limitations

Tags: javascript, jquery

My web project has a dropdown menu within a div element.  Calling the javascript function HideDropdown hides the menu when any other main link on the page is clicked (not including links in the dropdown menu itself).

I also want to call HideDropdown() to hide the menu (if it's open) when I click anywhere on the body except the dropdown menu itself.  I created a javascript click handler function, but it doesn't hide the menu (it does nothing).

Here is the new javascript click handler (placed right below the body tag):

```
<script>
body.onclick = function(event) {
  target = event.target;

if (target != "#dropdown-content-id") {
  if (target != "#dropdown-content-id2") {
    HideDropdown();
    };
  };
};
</script>
```

Here is the relevant part of the html code:

```
<div class="C1"><br>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="button_01" onclick="HideDropdown();ShowDXT(2);ShowDropdown();">  Display Data Segments</button>
</div></div>

<div id="dropdown-content-id">
   <div class="C1"><button class="button_dropdown" onclick="ReadData(1)">Data   One</button></div>
   <div class="C1"><button class="button_dropdown" onclick="ReadData(2)">Data   Two</button></div>
   <div class="C1"><button class="button_dropdown" onclick="ReadData(3)">Data   Three</button></div>
</div>
```

Here is the HideDropdown function:

```
 <script>
 function HideDropdown() {
     $("#dropdown-content-id2").hide();
     $("#dropdown-content-id").hide();}
 </script>
```

I know that a body click will hide the menu, but I need to specify that it hides only if the target is not the dropdown menu itself.

Thanks very much for any ideas.

EDIT 100818:

After some work, I whittled down my problem to this:  I can call the HideDropdown() function from the body tag like this:

```
<body onload="ShowAjax(1)" onclick="HideDropdown()">
```

That works.  But when I change it to the same function with qualifications and  (not if the click event is fired by the dropdown menu), the dev console says "TypeError: e is undefined" so it has something to do with the conditional statement:

```
<body onload="ShowAjax(1)" onclick="HideDropdown_B()">

<script>
function HideDropdown_B(e) {
    if(e.target.id != "dropdown-content-id" ){
        $("#dropdown-content-id2").hide();
        $("#dropdown-content-id").hide();}
}
</script>
```

So my problem now boils down to finding out why the new function above returns a type error when the same program without the if statement works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
var HideDropdown = function(e) {
        if(e.target.id != "dropdown-content-id" ){
            $("#dropdown-content-id2").hide();
            $("#dropdown-content-id").hide();
        }
    }

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('body').click(function(event) {
            target = event.target;

            if (target != "#dropdown-content-id") {
                if (target != "#dropdown-content-id2") {
                    HideDropdown(event);
                };
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have rewritten the script contents, You need to make sure to pass the event to HideDropdown or else it won't have access to it.

Comment: Thanks, Brice, but this does not work when inserted right below the body tag.  It does not seem to refer to a body click, could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, Brice.  I have two questions:  (1) you say to "pass the event to HideDropdown" -- is that not shown in the code above?  (2) Do you disable the existing HideDropdown function?  I tried this and it disables all dropdown menus.  I commented out the existing HideDropdown but the problem persists.  The dev console reports no errors, however.

Comment: 1) The code above now shows this here `HideDropdown(event);`, it didn't before.
2) you shouldn't have the existing `HideDropdown` function anymore only the one above, you're hiding the whole drop down section with `$("#dropdown-content-id").hide();`. I'm not sure what you want to happen? although I didn't implement these two functions so I'm not sure what they are supposed to do `ShowDXT(2);ShowDropdown();`

Comment: Brice, I edited my question above.  The problem is I can call the HideDropdown function from the body tag, but with an if-statement it throws an error.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: change `onclick="HideDropdown()"` to `onclick="HideDropdown(event)"`

Comment: Thanks again.  See my answer below.  I chose your answer and upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call  HideDropdown(); on each click if menu is open then it close

Answer (score 0):

Helped in part by the excellent feedback from Brice, I solved this problem.  Here is the solution:

In the body tag:

```
<body onload="ShowPage(1)" onclick="HideDropdown_B(event)">
```

The HideDropdown_B function:

```
<script>
function HideDropdown_B(event) {
    TargetID = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    TargetClass = event.target.getAttribute('class');
    if((TargetID != "dropdown-content-id") && (TargetClass != "button_01") &&   (TargetClass != "dropdown") && (TargetClass != "button_dropdown") ) {
   $("#dropdown-content-id2").hide();
       $("#dropdown-content-id").hide();}
}
</script>
```

That works to close the menu when clicking anywhere except the excluded elements.